# Enable SQL Server managed backup to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I was trying to Enable SQL Server managed Backup to Azure.
Using SAS token to create the Credentials in SQL.

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [Container_name]    WITH IDENTITY = 'Shared Access Signature',   SECRET = 'Secret_Key'
```

I can see the credentials been created successfully. Then executing the Backup configuration.

```
EXEC managed_backup.sp_backup_config_basic      
      @enable_backup =   1,
      @database_name = 'DB_Name',
      @container_url = 'Container_URL',
      @retention_days =  '10'
```

Throwing following Error,

> Msg 45207, Level 17, State 17, Procedure
> managed_backup.sp_add_task_command, Line 102 [Batch Start Line 15] The
> operation failed because of an internal error. The argument must not
> be empty string. Parameter name: sasToken Please retry later.
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(String
> paramName, String value)    at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials..ctor(String
> sasToken)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.SmartAdmin.SmartBackupAgent.FileService.VerifyContainerURL(String
> containerURL, SqlConnection conn)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.SmartAdmin.SmartBackupAgent.SmartBackup.ConfigureDbOrInstance(SmartBackupConfigParameters
> config, LogBaseService jobLogger, SqlConnection conn)

Tried with Different SAS Token, and the access.  But still facing same issue.